# How to use Facebook php-sdk via FOSFacebookBundle?

Tags: symfony, facebook-php-sdk, symfony-2.1, fosfacebookbundle

I want to use the Facebook's PHP-SDK in a Symfony2 project to send notifications. How is the best way to get the PHP-SDK in a controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having FOSFacebookBundle installed and configured, you can get the PHP SDK inside a controller like this:

```
$facebook = $this->container->get('fos_facebook.api');
```

The following would get the Facebook user id if logged in for instance:

```
$uid = $facebook->getUser();
```